# How to get the no of Days from the difference of two dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

```
select extract(day from age('2013-04-06','2013-04-04'));`
```

gives me the no of days ! i.e.: `2` days

but it failed when I have a differnt month:

```
select extract(day from age('2013-05-02','2013-04-01'));
```

So what I need is to get the no of days as `32` days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtraction seems more intuitive.

```
select '2013-05-02'::date - '2013-04-01'::date
```

Run this query to see why the result is 31 instead of 32

```
with dates as (
  select generate_series('2013-04-01'::date, '2013-05-02'::date, '1 day')::date as end_date,
                         '2013-04-01'::date as start_date
)
select end_date, start_date, end_date - start_date as difference
from dates
order by end_date
```

The difference between today and today is zero days. Whether that matters is application-dependent. You can just add 1 if you need to.